# How to change color of div on link click and then when other link is clicked, another div changes color, previous is set to default color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I have a link that lieds me to specific `<div>` on my page. This is a page content. When i click on link, send me to specific place on my page (title of table). I'd like, that when i click on that link, the `<div>` (title of table) is colored red. Then when i click on another link (another `<div>` and another title of table) previous `<div>` is colored back in black and new `<div>` is colored red...etc.

This is my code so far:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<button onclick="SetAllTitleColorToBlack()">Refresh page</button>
    <td>
        <div id="kazalo" height="50" style="padding-left:25; font-size:16px"> <b><u>Page content:</u></b>
            <b><ul>
                <li> <a href="#one"> link to one </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#two"> link to two </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#three"> link to three </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#four"> link to four </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#five"> link to five </a></li>

            </ul></b>
        </div>
    </td>
        <script> <!-- script, da kazalo strani sledi strani, če gremo dol, gre tudi kazalo dol -->
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                $('#kazalo').stop().animate({
                    'marginTop': $(window).scrollTop() + 'px',
                    'marginLeft': $(window).scrollLeft() + 'px'
                }, 'slow');
            });
            var totaltext = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
                    break;
                }
                totaltext += 'scroll!<br />';
            }
            window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
            $('#div2').html(totaltext);
        </script>
    <td style="padding-left:50">        
        <div id="one"> one </div>
        <div id="two"> two </div>
        <div id="three"> three </div>
        <div id="four"> four </div>
        <div id="five"> five </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So when i click on `"link to one"` page moves me to `<div>` with `id="one"` and title `"one"` must be colored red. If i click now on `"link to three"`, page moves me to `<div>` with `id="three"` and title `"three"` must be colored red, title `"one"` must be colored in default color, so black in this case.

I also need a refresh button, when i click on this button, all colors of titles are set to default (black) color.

Thanks for or the help

Comment: Hey @Klemen - when you ask questions on Stack, remember to isolate your example code into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Debugging code is far easier this way and you'll get a swifter response.

Comment: What is "CP" in your code? Can you provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
div:target {
  color:red;
}
```

to color divs when clicked with css.

For reset you could just make a empty link `<a href="#"> reset </a>`

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbJqva) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You could add / remove an class (active for example) to the specific div. The example below shows this - you would however need to make some minor changes.

First Part

```
<li> <a class="navLink" href="#one"> link to one </a></li>

<td id="myContent" style="padding-left:50">        
    <div id="one"> one </div>
    <div id="two"> two </div>
    <div id="three"> three </div>
    <div id="four"> four </div>
    <div id="five"> five </div>
</td>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $('.navLink').click(function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $($(this).attr('href')).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Css

```
<style>
    .active { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
</style>
```

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/y05ub9bk/